# Ansible map network drive issue

Tags: windows, ansible

Below is my ansible playbook.

---

## This Playbook will map network drive

- name: Map Network Drive
  hosts: xx.xxx.x.xxx
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  - name: Run Script
    win_command: C:\Windows\System32\net.exe use h:\ \xx.xxx.xx.xxx\AppDeploy /USER:domain@user password /persistent:yes

The error I am getting after running the playbook is:

> *
>   fatal: [10.135.2.141]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "C:\Windows\System32\net.exe use h:\ \\10.135.10.209\AppDeploy /USER:domain@user password /persistent:yes", "delta": "0:00:00.046800", "end": "2017-06-25 09:18:57.709450", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-06-25 09:18:57.662650", "stderr": "The syntax of this command is:\r\n\r\nNET USE\r\n[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]\r\n        [/USER:[domainname\]username]\r\n        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]\r\n        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]\r\n        [/SMARTCARD]\r\n        [/SAVECRED]\r\n        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]\r\n\r\nNET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME\r\n\r\nNET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]\r\n\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["The syntax of this command is:", "", "NET USE", "[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]", "        [/USER:[domainname\]username]", "        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]", "        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]", "        [/SMARTCARD]", "        [/SAVECRED]", "        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]", "", "NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME", "", "NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]", ""], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
>           to retry, use: --limit @/playbooks/map_drive.retry
>
> PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
>   10.135.2.141               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. I am able to map the drive using below:
 - win_command: net use "Z:" "\10.135.10.209\AppDeploy" /user:"domain\user" "PASS" /persistent:yes